# New process that got created using "CreateProcessAsUser" API is a child of the creating process

Tags: c#

I have a windows service (process - x) launching another GUI application (MVVM) (process - y) but process y is a child of process x. Even though these processes run as different user accounts for some reason the log file that is being created for process y is being created at a location that is valid for process x. %USERPROFILE% environment variable is being used in the path to the log file. So, for process x which is running as "LocalSystem" account the environment variable is being evaluated to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile. For process y which is running as a current logged-in windows user the environment variable is being evaluated to process x's value instead of C:\Users[loginID]. This is because process y is a child of process x. So, I need to know how to break that parent-child relationship.

I use CreateProcessAsUser API to create process y from process x.

```
        // flags that specify the priority and creation method of the process
        int dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;

        // create a new process in the current user's logon session
        bool result = CreateProcessAsUser(usertoken,                                                        // client's access token
                                        null,                                                        // file to execute
                                        String.Format("{0} {1}", applicationName,  arguments),                     // command line
                                        ref sa,                                                                 // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                        ref sa,                                                                 // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                        false,                                                                  // handles are not inheritable
                                        dwCreationFlags,                                                        // creation flags
                                        IntPtr.Zero,                                                            // pointer to new environment block 
                                        workingDirectory,                                                         // name of current directory 
                                        ref si,                                                                 // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                                        out procInfo                                                            // receives information about new process
                                        );
```

Please let me know how to remove the parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `CreateProcessAsUser` only runs the process with the given user's credentials (security context), but not with any profile information.

The MSDN page [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggests loading the profile and environment block using `LoadUserProfile` and `CreateEnvironmentBlock`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was able to resolve the issue by calling the CreateEnvironmentBlock using the usertoken for launching process - y.Also, when the environment block is being passed in to CreateProcessAsUser we need to make sure that CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT creation flag is used.

Comment: @CP1: Indeed, the `CreateEnvironmentBlock` function creates a Unicode environment block for you, so when you pass it to `CreateProcessAsUser` you need to tell it that it is Unicode (without it, it assumes ANSI)